# angularjs computed property not updating after model changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple activity viewer in a table that lists activities and their statuses (read or not read) from a db. On the page is a counter that shows how many activities are unread. Each activity gives the option to `mark read` or `mark unread` depending on the condition. For some reason after the `model` is being updated the computed value is not changing on the counter.

**Controller**

```
function Activity($scope, $http, $templateCache)
{
    $http.get('/activity/get').success(function(data, status)
    {
        $scope.activities = data;
    });

    $scope.totalActivities = function()
    {
        var count = 0;

        angular.forEach($scope.activities, function(activity)
        {
            count += activity.seen == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        });

        return count;
    }

    $scope.updateActivity = function(activity)
    {
        activity.seen = activity.seen == 0 ? 1 : 0;

        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url:    '/activity/' + activity.id,
            data:   { seen: activity.seen }
        })
        .success(function(data, status)
        {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

**Counter**

```
<span class="badge badge-alert">{{ totalActivities() }}</span>
```

**Table row + button**

```
<tr ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-class="{ 'activity-read': activity.seen == 1 }"> 
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateActivity(activity)"><span>@{{ 0 == activity.seen ? 'Mark Read' : 'Mark Unread' }}</span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**nav template (separate code block)**

```
<div class="account-details" ng-controller="Activity">
    @if (Sentry::hasAccess('admin'))
    <a href="{{ route('activity.index') }}" class="activity pull-left">
            <span class="badge badge-alert">@{{ totalActivities() }}</span>
        </a>
    @endif
</div>
```

The counter works fine when first loaded but any updates to the model need a page refresh for the new calculation to show.

Comment: the best way to get an answer would be to set up a jsfiddle or plnkr that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something tells me we aren't seeing the relavant bits of your code here.

When I [recreate your example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/EBSB4/) using `$timeout` instead of `$http` everything is working just fine:

```
var Activity = function($scope, $timeout) {
    console.log('creating controller');

    var fakeData = [
          {name: 'One',   seen: 0}, 
          {name: 'Two',   seen: 0},
          {name: 'Three', seen: 1},
          {name: 'Four',  seen: 0}
    ];

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.activities = fakeData;
        console.log('data returned');
    }, 500);

    $scope.totalActivities = function () {
        var count = 0;

        angular.forEach($scope.activities, function (activity) {
            count += activity.seen === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        });

        return count;
    };

    $scope.updateActivity = function (activity) {
        activity.seen = activity.seen === 0 ? 1 : 0;

        var payload = {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/activity/' + activity.id,
            data: {
                seen: activity.seen
            }
        };

        $timeout(function () {
            console.log(payload);
        }, 200);
    };
};
```

jsFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/EBSB4/

Comment: So I moved the counter around a bit and seems like it's a `scope` issue possibly? See updated code in my question. The counter is in a separate div outside of the original calling controller. I moved the `ng-controller` block up so it includes both the counter and the table. Is that just the best way to go about it?

Comment: I figured out my `$scope` issue once I discovered `$emit` and `$on`. I setup a parent controller and sent the value up from the child controller and voila! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled for a while with computed properties and $watch and so on, couldn't imagine that it should be so difficult, then I found this solution:

[What is the analog for Knockout's writable computed observable in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526938/what-is-the-analog-for-knockouts-writable-computed-observable-in-angularjs/19548980#19548980)

Just use the power of Javascript itself to define an object getter and setter. No need for $watch, brilliantly simple.